# Derivative of Equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

So i have this problem with the function:
$$U(x)=\frac{A^2}{x^2} - \frac{A}{x}$$
I need to find the derivative of $U$ to find the min and max values. It says in the problem that $A$ is a positive constant and $x > 0$.

So i use the sum/difference rule of derivatives while using the quotient rule. Here is my work:

$$    U'(x) = \left(\frac{(x^2)(2A \cdot 0) - (A^2)(2x)}{x^4}\right) - \left(\frac{(x)(0)-(A)(1)}{x^2}\right)$$
$$    U'(x) = \frac{-2xA^2}{x^4}-\frac{A}{x^2}$$

Would that be the right answer? Can i somehow simply that anymore?

Comment: Yes it is correct up to a sign mistake in the second line. It is $+A/x^2$ and you can simplify $x$ in $-2xA^2/x^4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct, you just have a sign mistake in the second expression of $U'(x)$. We have
$$U'(x) = \frac{-2xA^2}{x^4}-\frac{-A}{x^2} = \frac{A}{x^2}-\frac{A^2}{x^3}.$$

Comment: I have a question i think you can answer. Finding min. and max. values means setting the derivative to zero. When doing that i get `x=2A` as one. But would zero also be one because it is where ever the derivative is undefined?

Comment: @user2166592 no... and anyway it is given in your problem that $x>0$ ("$A$ is a positive constant and $x>0$").

Comment: right forgot about that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule for division works, but for this you can simply take the derivative of a polynomial.

$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}[
(A^2)/(x^2) - A/x] & = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} [A^2x^{-2} - Ax^{-1}]
\\[1ex]
& = A^2 \frac{\mathrm d x^{-2}}{\mathrm d x} - A\frac{\mathrm d x^{-1}}{\mathrm d x}
\\[1ex]
& = A^2 (-2x^{-3}) - A(-x^{-2})
\\[1ex]
& = \frac{-2A^2}{x^3}+\frac{A}{x^2}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

It's correct with the sign correction someone else mentioned (you forgot to distribute the $-$ for the second term), but you can simplify the first term more, because $\frac{x}{x^4} = \frac{1}{x^3}$. However, there's a simpler way to think about this problem. When you have exponents in the denominator, you can think of them as negative exponents in the numerator. So before taking the derivative, you can rewrite your function like this: $$U(x) = A^2x^{-2} - Ax^{-1}$$ and use the power rule.